# upload files with loop in bigquery with python. Missing Data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a simple loop reading a set of 17 json files (with less than 25 rows each) and uploading them into a bigquery table. This is the code

```
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
job_config.autodetect = True

seq_months =('201703','201704','201705','201706','201707','201708','201709','201710','201711','201712',
            '201801','201802','201803','201804','201805','201806','201807')
y=0
for y in seq_months:
    json_file= 'C:\\reviews_com.llollo.bipi_%s.json' % (y)
    print(json_file)
    with open(json_file,'rb') as readable:
        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(readable, table_ref, location='US', job_config=job_config)
        print(json_file)
```

I can see by the `print` function that the loop is running correctly.
However, I am only uploading some months in the table. Does anyone know what is happening? I am missing data.

Comment: In line with your "with open..." line, add job.result()  and then below that print('Loaded {} rows from {} into {}:{}.'.format(job.output_rows, json_file, dataset_id, table_id) to see if that helps clarify what's happening

Comment: Thanks! The problem was related with the formating.

Comment: Glad you've found it!

Comment: Hi Marina, I'm glad you found the solution! Could you post it as an answer so is more visible for others with the same problem? Also, you will be able to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after two days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment of Guillermo I found that my problem was in the formating of some columns ex. FLOAT when the schema is INTEGER. Here the entire code:

```
seq_months=('201703','201704','201705','201706','201707','201708','201709','201710','201711','201712',
                '201801','201802','201803','201804','201805','201806','201807')
        y=0
        for y in seq_months:
            json_file= 'C:\\Users\\lloll\\Desktop\\google_play\\retained_installers\\retained_installers_com.llollo.bipi_%s_%s.json' % (y,type_data)
            print(json_file)
            with open(json_file,'rb') as readable:
                job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(readable, table_ref, location='US', job_config=job_config)
            job.result()
            print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```